# How to get NOT Equal functionality using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get all those records from **vehicles** who have no match in **HireGroupDetails** but don't know how to get **NOT EQUAL** functionality in **LINQ** !

```
var fleetHireGroupDetailQuery = from vehicle in db.Vehicles                
                                join hgd in db.HireGroupDetails on
                    new { vehicle.VehicleMakeId, vehicle.ModelYear }
                    equals new {  hgd.VehicleMakeId,  hgd.ModelYear}
                    select new RptFleetHireGroupDetail
                     {
                          PlateNumber = vehicle.PlateNumber,
                     };
```

Comment: Can't you just use !equals?

Comment: Why can't you query HireGroupDetails, using hgd.VehicleMakeId == null?

Comment: !equals not works ! @sebbzzz

Comment: would have thought that this wasn't even a technically challenging thing. Could have used Linq functions to make it easier. I'm still pretty sure you can do basic equality operators in a where clause of a Linq expression

Comment: Well first of all you wouldn't do a join if they have nothing in common! Do HireGroupDetails and Vehicles have the same columns?

Comment: yes same as well as some additional ones @Tyress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
var fleetHireGroupDetailQuery = from vehicle in db.Vehicles
                                where !(from hgd in db.HireGroupDetails
                                select new {  hgd.VehicleMakeId,  hgd.ModelYear}).Contains(new { vehicle.VehicleMakeId, vehicle.ModelYear })
                    select new RptFleetHireGroupDetail
                     {
                          PlateNumber = vehicle.PlateNumber,
                     };
```